# Anyone know where to get the micro version of DD-WRT?

Tags: router

I would like to turn my extra wireless router into a wireless bridge so that I don't have to buy a card for my Xbox 360.  I have found [an article on how to do so with DD-WRT](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-turn-an-old-router-into-a-wireless-bridge/) (if there is an easier way please tell me).  The router is a [Netgear WGR614 v6](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Netgear) which according to the DD-WRT compatability list has 2MB of Flash memory and hence [can use only DD-WRT Micro](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Note_on_devices_with_2.C2.A0MB_flash).  I am searching through their downloads page and for the life of me I can't find anything named DD-WRT Micro.  Can anyone point me to the download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the hardware search page and enter your router in. If it is in the hardware database, it will then present you with versions of firmware that you can download (after clicking on the router). This is also the way to get firmware versions that are not available on the direct download page.

Answer (score 1):

Your router may not work.  Read this thread first:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=36438&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=wgr614&start=0

Comment: Meh.  This router is useless so I really don't care if I brik it.  It sounds like there still might be a chance.  But I have no idea which version I should download. Even v24 sp1 micro generic has several different versions.